# Install unpacked Chrome extension for multiple users

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am trying to install an unpacked extension in Google Chrome for multiple users in our organization. The extension is hosted on an internal file server.

Does anyone know how this can be done as a Chrome administrator?

Edit: We are on Windows OS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, for security reasons, previous methods for installing unpacked
extensions were judged as open to malware abuse.
The result is that
[it's no longer possible to add an extension programmatically on Windows](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html)
unless the extension is installed from the Store,
and I suppose that this is also true for other operating systems.

If your extension is published in the store, you can
[add it semi-automatically via registry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry),
but the user will still be asked whether to enable it on the next load.

If the computer is part of a Windows domain and you have admin rights
on the domain policy, then you can install extensions silently
[using Enterprise policy](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453).

On [other OSes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#preferences),
you may only load it unpacked for testing with the
[`--load-extension` command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension),
but this will not persist after Chrome is restarted.

You may also install the extension on each user's computer by going into
`chrome://extensions/`, enabling *Developer mode* and clicking "Load unpacked".
Barring any errors, that should drop the extension directly into Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for commenting on this. Server and clients are in a Windows environment, so silent installation as described in the article you refer to is our best bet? https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948?visit_id=636767652636445282-2229569490&rd=1

Comment: Yes, if it fits your environment.